# How to incorporate time varying group covariates in linear mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I have a continuous response $Y_{ij}$ after taking repeated measures in an individual $i$. Altogether I measure $Y_{ij}$ 5 times  (j=1..5) under different types of subject motion: still1, still2, nod, shake and free. 
I also measure how much each subject moved in each of these motion types and this variable ($m_{ij}$) increases based on the type of motion (little in still, more in nod, more in shake and most in free motion). Now when comparing $Y$ across motion types (paired testing) I find that $Y_{ij}$ is significantly different across types, but that could simply be a result of the motion severity rather than the type of motion.

When running a simple mixed effects model on all data:

$Y_{ij} = b_i + \beta_0 + \beta_1 * m_{ij} + e_{ij}$

(with the intercept as random effect) I find a very strong dependence of $Y$ on $m$. Indicating that motion explains $Y$ very well.

Now how can I test if motion type actually matters or not? I thought of these two models ($nod_{ij}$, $shake_{ij}$ and $free_{ij}$ are binary variables that determine the motion type):

$Y_{ij} = b_i + \beta_0 + \beta_1 m_{ij} + \beta_2 nod_{ij} + \beta_3 (nod_{ij} \ m_{ij}) + \beta_4 shake_{ij} + \beta_5 (shake_{ij} \ m_{ij})  + \beta_6 free_{ij} + \beta_7 (free_{ij} \  m_{ij}) + e_{ij}$

and another model dropping the $\beta_2, \beta_4$ and $\beta_6$ terms.The reason behind dropping these is that there should be a single intercept for $m=0$ independent of the motion type (as there would be zero motion, so type does not matter)

1.) Do I always have to include the motion type intercepts ($\beta_2, \beta_4$ and $\beta_6$ terms) when I have interaction terms? Someone told me they should always be included, but it does not seem to make much sense here.

2.) In either model I can now test if there is a motion severity effect in each motion type independently (testing the interaction terms $\beta_3, \beta_5$ and $\beta_7$ independently). And I find these to be significant except in the 'still' type ($\beta_1$). This tells me that on top of whatever the motion type does, the motion severity explains a lot, right? However, I am unclear if motion type explains anything at all.

3.) For testing that, I need to compare the interaction terms (pairwise) and basically test, for example, $\beta_5 - \beta_7$. This would tell me, if depending on the motion type I get different slopes, right?

4.) So far so good, but I find the difference of the interaction terms only to be significant in one of the two models (the full one with all intercepts). The simplified (and in my opinion more meaningful model) does not show significance. Therefore I think it is very important to understand what model to use to interpret these results.

Any help is greatly apprechiated.